# Unclosed String Literal - Vue JS Template simple concatenation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, concatenation

Can anyone explain why this is happening?  New to Vue, and don't understand what's wrong?

This works:

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <div v-else>
            {{ remaining.hours > 0 ? (remaining.hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + remaining.hours + ':' : '' }}
```

However when I try to add a span, I get the 'unclosed string literal' error:

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <div v-else>
            {{ remaining.hours > 0 ? (remaining.hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + remaining.hours + '<span class="colon">:</span>' : '' }}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen example to reproduce the error ?

Comment: double quote inside single quote is not allowed. use back tick instead.
`{{ remaining.hours > 0 ? (remaining.hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + remaining.hours + \`<span class="colon">:</span>\` : '' }}` 
or use escape before double quote
`{{ remaining.hours > 0 ? (remaining.hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + remaining.hours + '<span class=\"colon\">:</span>' : '' }}`

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets interpret the data as plain text. For HTML use the v-html directive:

```
<div v-else v-html="remainingHtml">
```

```
computed : {
  remainingHtml () {
    return remaining.hours > 0 ? (remaining.hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + remaining.hours + '<span class="colon">:</span>' : '' :
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html